# Error when following the NEAR Certified Developer L1C4 introductory video

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm new to Near - just following along with [L1C4 NEAR Certified Developer](https://youtu.be/w6JlZpYMvpo) video and have hit a bit of a brickwall.

When trying to send a message (`./scripts/2.say-thanks.sh "Thanks for being here"`) I get the following error message:

```
Unable to find [ testnet ] credentials for [ jptest2.testnet ]...
Scheduling a call: dev-1642444729043-12324156214302.say({"message":"Thanks for being here"})
Doing account.functionCall()
TypedError: Can not sign transactions for account jptest2.testnet on network testnet, no matching key pair found in InMemorySigner(MergeKeyStore(UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(/Users/jeremy/.near-credentials), UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(/Users/jeremy/Projects/NCD.L1.sample--thanks/neardev))).
    at Account.signTransaction (/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:93:19)
    at async /Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:118:34
    at async Object.exponentialBackoff [as default] (/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/exponential-backoff.js:7:24)
    at async Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:117:24)
    at async scheduleFunctionCall (/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/commands/call.js:57:38)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9) {
  type: 'KeyNotFound',
  context: undefined
}
```

I get the same error when trying to run `./scripts/o-report.sh` .

Is there something I have to enable in the `jptest2.testnet` account to get things working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login locally with your account

Run `near login` which will open your NEAR Wallet in a web browser

authorize the account called `jptest2.testnet`

Comment: Thanks Sherif, all working now :)